# Invalid Info.plist value. The minimum value is 8.0

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, minimumosversion

I am working on an external(it is not available on Cocoa pods) framework who's **deployment target is 7.0** which I have set in **Xcode 9.2** (*although Xcode 9.2 shows only till iOS 8.0 I could successfully compile when I manually entered 7.0.)*

While I try and use the framework in sample application and upload the sample application to app store I get the following error:

> **iTunes Store Operation Failed ERROR ITMS-90362:**
>
> "Invalid Info.plist
> value. The value for the key 'MinimumOSVersion' in bundle
> SDKReference.app/Frameworks/****.framework is invalid. The
> minimum value is 8.0"

I tried adding `Minimum System Version` and `Minimum OS Version keys` in the info.plist but nothing worked.

**Note:**
I tried uploading a blank app with iOS 7.0 deployment target with Xcode 9.2. It was uploaded successfully.

Comment: yes, it is possible with older Xcode version, like e.g. with _Xcode 8.x_ offers supporting iOS7.

Comment: @holex But I am able to upload a simple app with 7.0 deployment target from Xcode 9.2.

Comment: you just hacked the value in Xcode, which does not count. really. Xcode 9.x supports iOS8+ only, you need Xcode 8.x for supporting iOS7 – or alternatively your client could drop iOS7 support.